# Can I search the available Context Menu Commands in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

If I right-click on the toolbar > click Customize > click Commands tab > then click the Context Menu radio button, there are a rather large amount of choices.  Sometimes what I'm trying to find an item to add or remove, I have to wade through a lot of the choices before I finally find the item and looking for (if I even can). Sometimes the groups are not at all intuitive.

Is there any way I can search the available options in all categories? In Visual Studio itself, or even an extension.

Comment: What about this issue? Actually I agree with GusP's suggestion, I often use the Quick Launch to find certain menu commands if I couldn't find it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I use:

1. If you're trying to *search* for something specific, Quick Launch
   should be pretty useful to you. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> will take you to it or just
   type in the text box in the top right of the main VS window.
2. Another option that comes to mind: go to Tools->Customize and click
   on the *Keyboard* button. That has a search box for commands that
   can also be useful. Tip: make the window bigger to make the list
   larger.